# LIMIT not working in SQL

Tags: sql-server

In my below Query:

```
Select * from DimCustomer 
order by MiddleName desc LIMIT 5
```

Getting below error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Comment: Like human languages, SQL has dialects. Make sure you always check the documentation for the specific database engine you are using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sql Server doesn't use `limit` like that, it uses `top` instead.

```
 select top 5 * from DimCustomer order by MiddleName desc
```

If you are looking for pagination, you can use `offset` and `fetch` in sql server 2012+

```
select * 
from DimCustomer 
order by MiddleName desc
offset 0 rows
fetch next 5 rows only;
```

For more patterns and options for pagination, check here: [Pagination with `offset / fetch` : A better way - Aaron Betrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)

Comment: @user3652369 because you are on sql server ?

Comment: Yes i am on SQL server using MSSQL 2012 and database is AdventureWorksDW2012